# How to find infinity that occurs in my java object?

Tags: java, spring

So I have an object of the type ProductionTest that needs to be saved via the spring framework. When saving it gives me an error on `session.flush();` which says `SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception java.sql.SQLException: 'Infinity' is not a valid numeric or approximate numeric value`
So it seems one of the Floats or Doubles I am trying to save is infinity. The issue is that ProductionTest is absolutely massive in the sense that it contains Lists of other objects that each have 9 objects that each have Floats and variables, therefore checking each Float or Double in the debug would take ages.
Is there a way I can automate this or make the process faster? Maybe automate it somehow?

```
        {
            if(cfam.getRecId()!=null) 
            {
                session.update(cfam);
            } 
            else {
                session.save(cfam);
            }
        }
        save = (Integer) session.save(prodTest);
        prodTest.setRecId(save);
        //my double is for debug purposes
        Double mydouble = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        session.flush();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
```

snippet of the part where it breaks

Comment: Are you able to provoke the problem on your machine and run it through a debugger? If so you could try to grab the Hibernate sources and put a break point where the exception is thrown. Then work your way up the call hierarchy from there to identify the offending property. In practice the value "infinity" is most likely the result of some calculation, especially a division. So I'd check those first.

Comment: have you actually debugged the code?

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce it on my machine.
Yes, I did put a breakpoint on the session.flush() On that breakpoint the variables are mydouble(which i made to see how infinity looks in debug window), prodTest(what is probably actually causing the problem), save, session. 
I can open the prodTest hierarchy but manually working my way through it would probably take 10 hours or something since it has a lot of things in it.

Comment: @Thomas when you say grab hibernate sources what do you mean? You dont mean go in debug mode and look at the object, do you?

Comment: Well, I assume you're using an IDE so you should be able to link the *-sources.jar files for the Hibernate libraries and step into the code. If you're using Maven or Gradle to build your application getting the sources should be easy and if your IDE has support for those build systems then linking them should also be straight forward (e.g. using Ecplise + Maven this is basically just a "Maven->Download Sources" command). Once you have the sources try to step through the Hibernate code like I explained.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found a solution to this. I simply went into the ProductionTest class and generated a new toString method. Then I added a console print

```
 String output = prodTest.toString();
 System.out.println(output);
```

Then I copied the 10k char result from the console and pasted it in notepad++ and ctrl+f and searched for infinity. Found the double that was infinite.